# How do I reference related record (__r) field value from query

Tags: soql, related-list

I don't know how to reference the value of the `Job_Matching_Title__r.Salary_Range_Avg__c` field from this query:

```
List<Position__c> Positions = [SELECT Name, Department__c,  Job_Matching_Title__r.Name, Job_Matching_Title__r.Salary_Range_Avg__c FROM Position__c WHERE Department__c = :StringDepartmentID];

for (Position__c p :Positions){
    system.debug('Average Salary: ' + Job_Matching_Title__r.Salary_Range_Avg__c );
}
```

The error message is:

> "Variable does not exist"

I'm expecting to see a numeric value.
I can run the query in the Schema Explorer so the query seems fine, I just don't know how to reference that related record field value.

Thanks,

Kevin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot the `Position p` object in your loop.

Try :

```
List<Position__c> Positions = [SELECT Name, Department__c,  Job_Matching_Title__r.Name, Job_Matching_Title__r.Salary_Range_Avg__c FROM Position__c WHERE Department__c = :StringDepartmentID];

for (Position__c p :Positions){
    system.debug('Average Salary: ' + p.Job_Matching_Title__r.Salary_Range_Avg__c );
}
```

Comment: You're welcome.